# Undo resolve with tortoise svn?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

1. I modified my local files (lots of important things)
2. I tried to commit, but there were some conflicts
3. I just updated (download distant files) and resolved conflicts (hoping it would replace "distant" files by my local files/working copy).

It didn't do what I expected.

How can I revert my files as they were after point 1.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not possible assuming you marked the conflicts as resolved.  Once that happens, the three versions of the conflicted file (yours, the repositories, and their common ancestor) are merged into one (the resolved version that you said resolves the conflict) and removed from your working copy.

It sounds like you misunderstood what resolving a conflict is supposed to do.  [Conflict resolution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve) does not modify anything on the repository; it's purely a local (on your machine) operation.

Comment: mh, so I lost my files.

Comment: Yeah "resolve" doesn't resolve anything!  It just makes a mess of your file in which the conflict occurred which makes SVN ignore the fact it's still in conflict!  "Permanently Ignore Conflict" would have been a far more suitable label for this pointless action!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done file-by-file with VsDiffMerge if you haven't deleted the files from your Recycle Bin that SVN deleted to it with it's so-called "Resolve" feature.  Each file in conflict would have had a corresponding `.mine` and `.r1234` (where 1234 is a number generated by SVN (and apparently increments exclusively from the code it represents!)).

Follow these steps for each file:

1. Restore the `.mine` and `.r1234` files from the Recycle Bin
2. Open command prompt
3. `cd` to the directory those files were restored in (e.g. `cd "C:\My Code\Project 1\My File.cs"`)
4. Locate vsDiffMerge.exe for your installation of Visual Studio (for Visual Studio 2019 it is usually: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\vsDiffMerge.exe")
5. Run vsDiffMerge.exe as follows (instructions for Visual Studio 2019):
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\vsDiffMerge.exe /m "My File.cs.r1234" "My File.cs.mine" "My File.cs.mine" "My File.cs"`
6. An instance of Visual Studio should now appear allowing you to genuinely resolve the conflicts between the `.r1234` file and `.mine` file and save the merged results into the `.cs` file which SVN messed-up with its fake resolve!

Comment: Just to add, if you don't fancy going file-by-file through all those steps, you could restore all the `.r1234` and `.mine` files and write a command-prompt program to invoke vsdiffmerge against any `.cs` file with a corresponding `.mine` and `.r1234` file in the same folder.

Comment: The following script for a batch file may also be useful: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\vsDiffMerge.exe" /m "%~1.r%2" "%~1.mine" "%~1.mine" "%~1"`.  Usage: `"My Batch File.bat" "My Source Code.cs" 1234`, where 1234 is the number on the end of the `.r` extension file.